# Lower bound and upper bound types for scala and dotty

Tags: scala, generics

Martin Odersky [mentioned](https://youtu.be/9lWrt6H6UdE) that they introduced compound and intersection types in dotty. On his slides there were two pictures representing the difference in upper and lower bounds for old and new type system.

This is the old one:

[image]

This is the new one:

[image]

Can someone explain what actually `upper bound` for `T <: U` means?  Why it's infinite for current version of scala? How it would be differ for `T >: U` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `T <: U` (i.e. `T` is a subtype of `U` or `U` is a supertype of `T`) then `U` is an **upper bound** for `T` and `T` is a **lower bound** for `U`.

In Scala 2

```
T with U <: T
T with U <: U
U with T <: T
U with T <: U
```

In Dotty

```
T & U =:= U & T
T | U =:= U | T
T & U <: T
T & U <: U
T <: T | U
U <: T | U
```

If `T <: U` then

```
T with U =:= T
T & U =:= T
T | U =:= U
```

If `T >: U` then `U <: T` and vice versa

```
T with U =:= U
T & U =:= U
T | U =:= T
```

In Scala 2 if `T` and `U` are from different inheritance hierarchies (or more precisely, subtyping hierarchies) then the best what can be said is

```
T <: Any
U <: Any
```

In this sense upper bound is infinite.

Comment: but how T can be from different inheritance hierarchies than U if "T <: U" ? So U should be upper bound. That's what confusing me on the first picture.

Comment: In my answer I do not assume that T <: U. Generally T and U are two arbitrary types. T <: U only in those places in my answer where I explicitly write so. Regarding Martin's pictures I don't think it's written there that T <: U. It's a diagram in sence of relation "<:" i.e. "<:" is just in the center of diagram.

Comment: If T <: U then diagrams look differently, they simplify since `T with U =:= U with T =:= T & U =:= T`, `T | U =:= U`.

Comment: If T and U are two arbitrary types then T & U is the greatest lower bound for both T and U, T | U is the least upper bound for both T and U.